# Transparent background in a multiband raster using GeoServer

Tags: raster, geoserver, geotiff-tiff, sld

I have a raster with a black collar (background). I want to set those black pixels to transparent. The problem is that the values of the pixels have three bands (Red, Green and Blue) and I don't know how to define a rule in the .SLD to set those pixels which value is (0, 0, 0) to transparent.

[image]

Any idea on how to do this?

My question has been associated with another question. The answer to the other question resolves the problem for a single-band raster but in my case I have a multi-band raster, so the answer I need is different.